# How to find "This value is also used mostly with that value" with a tags table and an object table?

Tags: php, mysql

on my website (www.wyska.net) have the following tables:

tag

- id
- name
- uses  - number of times that a tag is mentioned on the table `_tag_wyska`

_tag_wyska

- wyska_id
- tag_id

and then a table `wyska` that is not important for now.

as the table `_tag_wyska` can have the same `wyska_id` with multiple entries, how can I find if a tag is used together with other tags and which tag is mostly used with ? and how would it be the best way to do it ? cache it or have a different table to keep up-to-date or.. ?

for example `wyska_id = abcd1234` has the following tags:

- politics
- strategy
- democrats

then the `wyska_id = 1234abcd` has the following tags

- strategy
- games
- league of legend

then one more `wyska_id = 7890defa` has the following tags

- strategy
- games
- people

I know that strategy was used 3 times, games 2 times, and the rest 1 time, but what I need to know is that the `strategy` tag was used MOSTLY with the word `game` so I will associate `game` and `strategy` together for example to suggest the user sub-search tags, or to find clever ways to analyze the data and create categories on the fly or.. just because is an interesting problem

Comment: read about sql `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` documentation :)

Comment: Not that easy. I am yalking about possibly milions of records and a group by that gives me the ones that have high usage and have another tag used might take seconds... Too long

Answer (score 0):

If you already know one of the tags you can use that to find the similarities:

```
SELECT tag.id, tag.name, COUNT(wyska_id) AS similarities
FROM _tag_wyska
LEFT JOIN tag ON tag.id = _tag_wyska.tag_id
WHERE wyska_id IN (
    SELECT wyska_id
    FROM _tag_wyska
    WHERE tag_id = '$SELECTED_TAG'
)
GROUP BY wyska_id
ORDER BY similarites DESC
```

May need a few tweaks, but the general idea is to select all wyska_ids that have the tag you want, then find the other tags with the highest count of the same wyska_ids.

Comment: The point is thay when i know a tag this would work, but i wqnt to suggest also based on the number or tags that have another tag used often with it. If a tag is used 5000 by itself, i dont want to show it, but if it has, lets say, 25% or more of the times something else associated with it then it is a valid tag.  Make sense ?